# Generate .aspx pages dynamically

Tags: asp.net, controls, code-behind, dynamically-generated, dynamic-controls

I have an `.aspx` page. It has some buttons and dropdown controls.

Let's say I click on a particular button then it must redirect to the page which we have to generate dynamically. This dynamically generated page will have of course dynamic controls and events. So basically what I want to know is how to generate this new `.aspx` page on click of existing page's button click, and how to add dynamic controls to the generated page's code behind.

Answer (score 2):

A way of doing this:

[How to create ASPX Page Dynamically - A Step Ahead Series?](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/26301-How-create-ASPX-Page-Dynamically-A-Step.aspx)

It doesn't sound good though.

Comment: Thanks daniel, i gone through this link. but want to generate aspx, its events, controls , control's event. how to do this?

Comment: Frankly, I've never seen something like this. Maybe you should think in other direction and try other type of solution.

Answer (score -2):

What about using `File.Create` to create the aspx file, then `response.redirect("newAspx file");`